# How can I disable "no existing match" when using the gem "rails3-jquery-autocomplete"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I'm using the gem called **rails3-jquery-autocomplete**
https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

It used not to show the message "no existing match" when there's no matched record.
However, now it always pops up the message showing `"no existing match"`

How can I disable this??

My view

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'search', params[:search], autocomplete_community_title_communities_path, :class =>'input', :placeholder => 'keyword' %>
```

Comment: I think this gem is dead, look at issues/pull requests on github, there are some forks that may work well for you, specifically this one: https://github.com/moser/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 2):

try below script

$('autocomplete_element_selector').on('autocompleteresponse', function(event, ui) {
        var content;
        if (((content = ui.content) != null ? content[0].id.length : void 0) === 0) {
          $(this).autocomplete('close');
        }
      });

Answer (score 0):

jQuery script provided by this Gem push this message if Rails return to client an empty hash (line at number 59 in public/javascript/autocomplete-rails.js):

```
...

if(arguments[0].length == 0) {
  arguments[0] = []
  arguments[0][0] = { id: "", label: "no existing match" }
}
jQuery(arguments[0]).each(function(i, el) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[el.id] = el;
  jQuery(e).data(obj);
});
response.apply(null, arguments);

...
```

I don't know, what exactly you want to do, but you can, for example, remove next block (or change label value) from your autocomplete-rails.js

```
if(arguments[0].length == 0) {
  arguments[0] = []
  arguments[0][0] = { id: "", label: "no existing match" }
}
```

This file should be located in your public/javascript directory. If this file is compressed in your case, you can uncompress it by this command from official documentation and then fix it:

> rails generate autocomplete:uncompressed